# Multiple variables with different relationships in nls() in R

Tags: r, function, regression, modeling, nls

I would like to build a model to predict Y based on several variables. First, I have a look on scatterplot and correlation map on R (see below)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KRfx.png)

It appears that Y has a **exponential relationship** with X1, a **logistics growth** with X2, and **linear relationiships** with X3 and X4. So, I was wondering that if it is possible to use `nls()` to build a model that may cover above relationship. Below is my try:

modelling Y~X2 solely in nls() to get phi parameters :

```
fit <- nls(Y~ c1*(exp(-k1*X1))+ SSlogis(Y, phi1, phi2, phi3) + X3+ X4,
               start=list(c1=Y[1], k1=0, phi1=15.07, phi2=1082.67,phi3=55.47))
```

Error:minFactor

Then try it differently:

```
fit <- nls(Y~ c1*(exp(-k1*X1))+ c2/(1+b2*exp(-k2*X2)) + X3+ X4,
               start=list(c1=Y[1], k1=0, c2 = 1, b2 = 0, k2 = 111))
```

Error: singularity

Q1: can I mix variables like above,if so, any thoughts how to fix errors

Q2: any thoughts on model selection(other models)

Comment: What is the purpose of the modelling? Can't you simply use a GAM?

Comment: It aims to predict heat consumption with weather conditions (air pressure etc.)

Comment: Then use a GAM. (Note that your plot does not show the partial relationships of your dependent to the predictors.)

Comment: @Roland, So can I just write the formula into gam() or should I specify initial values or using self-starting. thanks

Comment: You should start with finding out what a GAM is.